# Git commit fails: "assertion `g_type_from_name (name) == 0' failed"

Tags: git, ubuntu

I am a beginner in Git, and I tried to do my first commit.

After command `$ git commit` I got the following message:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gobject/constants.py:24: Warning: g_boxed_type_register_static: assertion `g_type_from_name (name) == 0' failed
  import gobject._gobject
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

- Ubuntu version: 12.04
- Git version: 1.7.9.5

**Added later:**
Now I am getting this message: **"Aborting commit due to empty commit message."**

My default editor is gedit.

Comment: I don't think that's a Git error, since I don't think Git contains any Python code. Do you have any commit hooks set up? (seems unlikely if this is your first experience with Git, but it seems reasonable to ask.)

Comment: What exactly is "commit hooks"? Just after Git installation I set email to Git the same one that I used for GitHub online account (which I also created just to have glance, no significant work has been done) which is probably irrelevant, but only I can remember. Thanks,.

Comment: A "commit hook" is an additional program that is run whenever you do a `git commit`. These are optional and are usually used for things like checking to see whether your source code or commit message conforms to a particular standard. Like I said, if this is your very first experience with Git, then you probably don't have any installed.

Comment: @all Please see the question update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `git commit -m "commit message"`. If this works, then maybe your problem is related to editor. Set your commit message editor to something working in terminal, like vim or nano

```
git config --global core.editor "nano"
```

and see if this works.

Comment: You're welcome. Try the second one too. Writing commit messages in editor will let you comfortably compose [longer descriptions of your changes](http://tbaggery.com/2008/04/19/a-note-about-git-commit-messages.html). -m is good only for really short ones.

Comment: OK, I did it. Gedit probably caused the first problem (before question editing) I have just saw on Wikipedia that it is developer in C and Python. Good to know what is going on. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

That might not be related to git (unless you are typing the git command from a python interpretor session!)

It would more likely be related with your current OS (Ubuntu 12.04) and its interaction with one of the software installed on it:
See [this Ubuntu bug 962639](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-defaults/+bug/962639), which reports the same kind of error messages.
Fixes are being experimented on `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gobject/constants.py` right now (April to June 2012).

Answer (score 1):

I used `git commit -a -m "My commit message"` for now.

Cheers